# Retrieve identity user with all navigation properties

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm working with authentication in `ASP.NET Web Api Core` and at some point I process user data:

```
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
...
var userLogins = await _userManager.GetLoginsAsync(user);
...
var userClaims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);
...
```

The problem is `GetUserAsync` does not load navigation properties, so I have to load them manually afterwards. Is there where a way to fix it without retrieving User object directly via `DataContext`?

Comment: you can get claims directly from the ClaimsPrincipal, but for everything else I think you need to handle the query yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a filter that queries User with all the navigation properties included and stores it to HttpContext.Items (per query collection).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using ASP.NET Core Identity, have you explored options with something like the [cookie middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie)?

You could run your own queries and get navigation properties with `.Includes()`, then build your own `ClaimsPrincipal`.